# RAID6 degraded drive during rebuild

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, raid-controller

**Background and context**

I have a 3ware LSI RAID controller and a RAID6 setup over 16 physical disks. One of the HDDs died last night, and I replaced it with a brand new (identical) drive this morning.

**Problem**

The command

```
/c0/u0 show
```

gives me

```
Unit     UnitType  Status         %RCmpl  %V/I/M  Port  Stripe  Size(GB)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
u0       RAID-6    REBUILDING     7%(A)   -       -     256K    6519.12   
u0-0     DISK      OK             -       -       p0    -       465.651   
u0-1     DISK      OK             -       -       p1    -       465.651   
u0-2     DISK      OK             -       -       p2    -       465.651   
u0-3     DISK      OK             -       -       p13   -       465.651   
u0-4     DISK      OK             -       -       p4    -       465.651   
u0-5     DISK      OK             -       -       p5    -       465.651   
u0-6     DISK      OK             -       -       p6    -       465.651   
u0-7     DISK      OK             -       -       p7    -       465.651   
u0-8     DISK      OK             -       -       p8    -       465.651   
u0-9     DISK      OK             -       -       p9    -       465.651   
u0-10    DISK      OK             -       -       p10   -       465.651   
u0-11    DISK      OK             -       -       p11   -       465.651   
u0-12    DISK      OK             -       -       p12   -       465.651   
u0-13    DISK      OK             -       -       p3    -       465.651   
u0-14    DISK      OK             -       -       p14   -       465.651   
u0-15    DISK      DEGRADED       -       -       p15   -       465.651   
u0/v0    Volume    -              -       -       -     -       6519.12
```

Which at first I was seriously concerned about (i.e. the new disk was bad too, or there was something wrong with the bay hardware), but the rebuild is progressing (I guess `(A)` means active) and `show alarms` doesn't give any errors;

```
c0   [Thu Aug 22 2013 23:14:32]  WARNING   Drive removed: port=15
c0   [Thu Aug 22 2013 23:14:32]  ERROR     Degraded unit: unit=0, port=15
c0   [Thu Aug 22 2013 23:14:32]  WARNING   Drive removed: port=15
c0   [Sun Aug 25 2013 08:53:27]  INFO      Drive inserted: port=15
c0   [Sun Aug 25 2013 08:54:33]  INFO      Rebuild started: unit=0
```

I wasn't managing the array the last time a disk failed, but last time the reports looked like this;

```
c0   [Thu Apr 11 2013 20:52:51]  WARNING   Drive removed: port=3
c0   [Thu Apr 11 2013 20:52:51]  ERROR     Degraded unit: unit=0, port=3
c0   [Thu Apr 11 2013 20:52:51]  WARNING   Drive removed: port=3
c0   [Fri Apr 12 2013 10:42:35]  INFO      Drive inserted: port=3
c0   [Fri Apr 12 2013 10:44:24]  INFO      Rebuild started: unit=0
c0   [Fri Apr 12 2013 15:10:21]  INFO      Rebuild completed: unit=0
```

So it *seems* like, from the alarms at least, what happened last time is happening again.

So - is it possible `degraded` in this context just means it's being rebuilt and so is currently out of action, or am I being brutally optimistic and do degraded errors just not show up in show alarms

**UPDATE**

As suggested - the disk rebuilt and everything seems A-OK!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, from the log it all is ok, or? Rebuild started, no error, rebuzils still in progress.

Comment: That's my thought as well, and I found [this post](http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/3Ware_RAID_Controller/en) which has a `degraded` disk show up during a rebuild. I guess I always associate `degraded` with nearly-dead-fix-me-now, but perhaps that's not the case here...

Comment: No, degraded means unprotected. And until the rebuild is finished, the RAID is in degraded state - one of the discs HAS failed. Only when the rebuild is finished it is ok. Now, I agree - it should show rebuilding, but hey, I dont write their software. THe log at leas shows now error. A progress report of the rebuild should show it going higher slowly.

Comment: Thanks - I guess part of this is that, ever the pessimist, I assume if something can go wrong it will!

Comment: Well, RAID 6 should protect you from that (another disc failing) ;)